# Can we make transaction directly from the proxy account?

Tags: pallet, proxy

I am working with proxy accounts. In which if i want make transection with by using proxy accounts It will happen like this:
[image: perform transaction using proxy]

As we can see to perform the transection from the proxy account first we need to select the main account by which the proxy account created then we have option to select the proxy option.

Can do the transection directly from the proxy account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The proxy pallet uses a very simple on-chain storage to map an account to the accounts it can proxy, and with what permissions.

Thus, to initiate any of those proxy operations, you must first start with a transaction coming from the account which has permissions to be the proxy for the account.

If you want to make calls directly from the proxied account, you will need to know its private key, and in that case, its not really a "proxied account" anymore, just a regular account...

Comment: Ok. One more thing.
After adding the proxy account we can make transection from the proxy account as well as the main account(without using proxy). 
Can we restrict it that we can only perform the transaction with proxy accounts?

Comment: I believe what was meant here with the question is the issue currently with Polkadot JS UI not letting you to do transactions with stash accounts that are not added to browser or extension wallet.  Which should be possible using polkadot-js-api proxy.proxy call somehow like:

proxy(real: AccountId32, force_proxy_type: Option<NodeRuntimeProxyType>, call: Call
meaning something in terms of 
```
api.tx.proxy.proxy(STASH.address, PROXY.type, (call)=> {
   here content of the transaction that gets decoded as a call.
});
```